# Enhancing program performance

Tags: c++, performance, cpu-usage

I'm still a beginner who tries to get the basics of c++ .I've been writing a Console application that prints out the prime numbers in a specific range and here is the code ( I'm using **CodeBlocks** ) :

```
bool isInteger(double i)
{
    int x = i;
    if ( i/x == 1)
    {
        return true;
    }else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

int DivTimes(double i)
{
    int counter = 0;
    for (int y = 2; y <= i; y++)
    {
        if (isInteger(i/y))
        {
            counter ++;
        }
    }
    return counter;
}

bool isPrime(double i)
{
    if (DivTimes(i) > 1)
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}

int main()
{
    for(int i = 999999910; i <= 1000000000 ; i++)
    {
        if (isPrime(i))
            cout << " " << i;
    }
}
```

for massive number like 1E9, the performance of my program becomes very slow and utilizes only 10% of my CPU. So, I was wondering is there any way that I can make my program utilize more CPU power and improve the program performance ?

Comment: You might want to do some research on efficient tests for primality.

Comment: if you take a closer look at that 10% do you get 10% of all of your computer's cores and ~100% of one core?

Comment: Semi-related: for best performance results make sure you are building code with optimization turned on and turned up. Not overly familiar with Code::Blocks, but that may be as simple as telling Code::Blocks to produce a "release" build.

Comment: Throw away all the stuff using doubles. Those are completely unnecessary and doesn't work all the time because of floating point error. To check if a number is divisible by another number, just check `a % b == 0`. Look up ways to generate primes in a certain range, as there are much more efficient algorithms than the one you're using.

Answer (score 1):

It should be pretty easy to improve the speed of this quite a lot.

The first step is based on simple math: the factors of a number match up in pairs: if one factor in a pair is larger than the square root of the number, then the other is smaller than the square root.

That means we only need to look at factors up to (and including) the square root of the number. If there's no factor less than or equal to the square root, there won't be any that's larger than the square root either. We can also stop looking as soon as we find one factor (other than 1), since that's enough to tell us the number isn't prime. Finally, we can start by trying to divide by 2. If the number divides by 2, it isn't prime, and we're done. Otherwise, we know it's odd, and we don't need to try dividing by any other even numbers. So, after checking for divisibility by two, we start our loop from 3, and add 2 each time instead of adding 1.

So let's consider the speed difference for 1e9. Right now, you're doing approximately 1e9 divisions. The square root of 1e9 is about 31,623. We only need to try dividing by the odd numbers, so we cut that in half, so the worst case is that we try dividing by 15,811 different numbers. So, in round numbers, we've sped up the job by a factor of about 1e9/15811 = 63,000.

If you want to go further, you could look up the Sieve of Eratosthenes. Using it, you can find all 50847534 primes up to 1e9 in about 30 seconds (takes about 29 seconds on my machine, using an old AMD A8-7600, which is not only 5 years old, but was a pretty slow CPU even when it was new).

There's quite a bit more you could do after that (Segmented Sieve, Sieve of Atkins, etc.) but that's probably enough to at least get you started.

As far as CPU usage goes: most of these are single threaded, so expect them to use 100% of one core, but that's it. Multithreaded prime searching might be somewhat non-trivial. I'd concentrate on using one core effectively first.

Oh--I almost forgot. For what (little) it's worth, here's some code for the most trivial version of the Sieve of Eratosthenes. It should be quite a bit faster than what you had, but it's still open to considerable improvement.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

unsigned long primes = 0;

int main() {
    int number = 1'000'000'000;
    std::vector<bool> sieve(number,false);
    sieve[0] = sieve[1] = true;

    for(int i = 2; i<number; i++) {
        if(!sieve[i]) {
            ++primes;
            for (int temp = 2*i; temp<number; temp += i)
                sieve[temp] = true;
        }
    }
    std::cout << "found: " << primes << " Primes\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer**: Don't.

**Long answer**:
This is probably most suited to ask in the Computer Science SE as it isn't about C++ but rather about algorithms.

There are plenty of things you can consider such as integrating multi threaded dynamic programming methods and merging them.  Even then you might end up with code that could potentially take years to run.

If you have a legitimate reason to use astronomical numbers then no C++ compiler is going to help you, you're better off using a specialised maths platform.  We used [Magma](http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/magma/) at the uni I went to.

You probably won't find anyone give you direct code as what you're trying to accomplish is not easy.  Good luck.